# How to import class for type hints in Python?

Tags: python

I have a code as:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
def func(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame
    ...
```

Since I don't actually create a DataFrame object in my code I wanted to do:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from pandas import DataFrame
def func(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame
    ...
```

This raises error:

```
E   NameError: name 'DataFrame' is not defined
```

How can I solve it?
Must I stay with the original import? It makes little sense to me to import a package that my code isn't really required but only for hints

Comment: When you are running the app DataFrame is imported somewhere inside library anyways (e.g. I guess DataFrame is imported in `__init__,py`, so if you import anything from pandas it will import everything from `__init__.py` and also will import things you don't even mind to import)

Comment: Have you tried `df: "DataFrame")` , note the quotes ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `from __future__ import annotations` so that no attempt is made to evaluate the expression at run-time; the annotations will be treated as implicitly quoted strings instead.

Comment: Is this the preferred way over just importing the library directly?

Comment: @Slava If you don't want to use a normal import, yes. using `"DataFrame"` to create a forward reference for the type that a type checker will understand instead of evaluating it at runtime also works